# Can' t understand endless scrolling with fetching data using PDO

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdo

I am trying to use endless scrolling plugin(https://github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll) with PHP code (PDO). Content, which must be loaded is the html-php file, which is linked in the index.php. Must be easy, but I can't understand, how to work correctly with linked html-php file(must I repeat html structure? must I connect to database second time? how to continue fetching from the same point where it stops in index.php? how to implement it generally?)

index.php

JS/ jQuery:

```
  <script>

       $('#posts').jscroll();
                $(function() {


    $('#posts').jscroll({
    loadingHtml: '<br/><span>Loading...</span>',
    padding: 20,
    nextSelector: 'a.jscroll-next:last',
    contentSelector: 'div',
    autoTrigger:true
});
</script>
```

php code:

```
session_start();

if ( isset( $_SESSION['login'] ) ) {
   $login    = $_SESSION['login'];
  $id=$_SESSION['id'];
$username="root";
$password="root";
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbname= "kotik";
function testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password){
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=kotik", $username, $password);
    return $dbh;
}

try {
    $dbh = testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);
    /* echo 'Connected to database'; */
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

php code in html:

```
<div id="posts" style="position:relative;width:100%;">
    <?php
    $title_select_query= $dbh -> prepare("SELECT title FROM books WHERE id = :id   ORDER BY date DESC");
        $title_select_query ->execute(array(':id' => $id));

     $title_select_query_result = $title_select_query->fetchColumn(); 
      echo('<div style="display:table; width:100%;"><div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width:100%;height:100px;position:relative;text-indent: 1.5em;font-family:esq;color:#5b5b5b;font-size:23px;border-bottom:6px solid #F3F3F3;  ">');

      print("$title_select_query_result ");
       echo('</div></div>');
  $title_select_query_result = $title_select_query->fetchColumn(); 
 echo(' <div style="display:table; width:100%;"> <div style="width:100%;height:100px;background:white;position:relative;border-bottom:6px solid #F3F3F3;text-indent: 1.5em;font-family:esq;color:#5b5b5b;font-size:23px;border-bottom:6px solid #F3F3F3;display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">');



  print("$title_select_query_result ");


  echo('</div><a href="loadmore.php"></a></div>');
?>
 </div>
```

So, what must be in the linked file according to what we have in index.php to continue fetching column ?

Comment: Look into MySQLs LIMIT command. Ie: start off with "LIMIT 0,9". This will give you max 9 records from position 0. Then on scroll you do "LIMIT 9,9". Which will give you max 9 records from position 9. This means you need to keep a counter on the client side that you increment on scroll.

Comment: @JimL Can you show implementation please? or link any article

Comment: sorry, the reason I only threw in a comment was that I have no time atm to write a proper answer.

Comment: What does the provided code currently produce?

Comment: @EternalHour 2(in this example, in my code - 5) posts with external HTML/CSS appearance which are scrolled  little bit down out of the standard browser window size . When user srolls to the end, next posts must be loaded(not implemented yet, asking you)

Comment: Seems to me that you should be using `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, not fetchColumn. Look at this [tutorial](http://www.w3bees.com/2013/09/jquery-infinite-scroll-with-php-mysql.html). It's a different plugin and mysql API but should show you what to do